# Is it possible to have two different instances of same Eclipse version?

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-juno

Its sounds awkward but its not wrong to ask this question i believe. I have an eclipse Juno running on my machine for java web application development.Now i got to install Android SDK for android development so i want to keep two different instances of eclipse Juno in my machine for Web and android development. I came across solutions like we can install different versions of eclipse but i don't want to download  different version of eclipse whereas i have eclipse Juno. Is is achievable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I'm talking about the windows OS and I am not sure about the rest.

As far as I know, you don't need to install eclipse. All you need is the files. Therefore you can have as many copies of it as you want.

However, my suggestion is that you download the ADT from the google site and use that.

Answer (score 2):

As long as you don't open the same workspace more than once at the same time, you can have multiple Eclipses. You'd just need to put the Eclipse files in different directories and create the appropriate shortcuts to access them.

But if all you're trying to do is to isolate your work, it's much easier to just use multiple workspaces. All you need to do that is to select File/Switch Workspace/Other... and specify a different directory.

Answer (score 1):

You can run the same version of Eclipse but cannot have them running at the same time using the same workspace.If you do, you will get the error message `"Workspace at ..../.../ in use or cannot be created, choose a different one"`.prompting you to use a different workspace.You can use one workspace for web development and another for Android.

Answer (score 1):

Well You can just add preference of Android to Eclipse JUno and if you don't want to do that you can use different workspace for Android and Web.

But if you want to install Same version Twice It wouldn't create proble use different WorkSpace to avoid Conflict.

Best Of Luck.